# Trying to call a function when user taps on screen. Android javascript for Minecraft pocket edition

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to call this function when the player taps anywhere on the screen? No buttons, this function is only called when the SCREEN not a button is pressed/ tapped. Please help me. How would I code this? When the user taps on the screen the function is called simply because they tapped on the screen.

```js
function MessageUser () {
  
  //Display a message in the chatbar:
  clientMessage("Hello");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

And you have not provided any details about your application, the only thing I could suggest is: try using [Touch events (MDN Reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events).

Using `touchstart` and `touchend` should be enough to get things started.

Comment: I am trying to build a mod for minecraft pocket edition. The main goal of the mod it to be able to make a message appear in the chat bar by simply tapping anywhere on the screen. How can I use touchstart and touchend as functions?

Comment: The player's field of view is rotated around by swiping your finger on the right hand side of the screen. You can't aim the player's field of view while pressing a button at the same time, so therefore I can't use buttons. Every example of detecting touch input for javascript I have seen involves some form of a button. But I can't use a button for this purpose... Is there a way to use touchstart function without a button? What I want is to make the whole screen a button if possible. I want to be able to detect touch input directly from the screen, not an html or DOM button.

Comment: No buttons at all, the only way to call the "MessageUser" function is to tap on the touch screen. No buttons should be involved or scripted in the code to make it work. No buttons, just the touch screen.

Comment: In the reference I've linked there is a ``Setting up the event handlers`` section. To make your whole screen a touch recording "button", replace ``canvas`` with ``body`` element. I'm afraid I won't be of any help further from this point, as I have no experience in using JavaScript on Android (TBH, I have no idea how are you going to make a Mod in JavaScript for a Java-written application).

Comment: It is possible using the program block launcher. It allows such things to happen as javascript working with java.

Comment: I cannot use any code related to web browsers, or html, the code is used in an app, not a web browser.